# How to access Spark nested struct fields from sql (not the DSL)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the following `sql` the syntax to access the nested `struct` is needed.

Specifically the following on the third line:

```
  collect_list(struct( .. ) )
```

I have put `rec.*` but that is certainly not the correct way.

```
select matchMethod, rec.* from
                              (select first(matchMethod) matchMethod,
                                collect_list(struct(rawTp,tp,fp,fn,
                                        precision,recall,weight,F1,
                                        truthGrpId,entityId,
                                        tpIds,fpIds, fnIds,truthIds,actuals)) rec
                                   from scoring5
                                      where entityId is not null and truthGrpId is not null
                                  group by truthGrpId
                              ) order by rec.truthGrpId, rec.recall desc
```

This results in :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(rec)`;
```

Many other ways have been attempted.  I have also perused about ten other questions here on SOF but none address this directly *specifically for the `SQL` and not the `DSL` ..*   Is this at all possible?

I am uncertain whether the message `Can only star expand struct data types` means that there may be a different syntax to achieve this, or whether spark sql simply has a deficiency here.

We are using `spark 2.3.X`.

Comment: AFAIK that is supported in neither SQL or DSL and you'll have to select each field (array) explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the significant research as well as trials of various combinations of syntax I tend to agree with @user6910411 that the above is not presently supported.  It seems there is some help coming along in the form of `Spark 2.4`: see this answer by Jacek Laskowski:

In any case I found a  more straightforward approach using `windowing` functions as follows:

```sql
select * from
  (select row_number() over (partition by truthGrpId order by recall desc) rownum,*
    from
    (select matchMethod, rawTp,tp,fp,fn,
        precision,recall,weight,F1,
        truthGrpId,entityId,
        tpIds,fpIds, fnIds,truthIds,actuals
      from scoring5
      where entityId is not null and truthGrpId is not null
    ) order by truthGrpId, recall desc
  ) where rownum=1 order by truthGrpId""")
```

[image]

The obvious follow-up here is to dig down deeper into `windowing` functions and incorporate them as first class citizens into my exploratory work.